# Reexporting external types in a npm package

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-types

I created a npm package which uses types from the definetely typed repo. I installed these types as devDependency on the npm package and I was able to use them just fine like this:

```
export class Example {
  constructor (options: ExternalTypes.Options) {}
}
```

However when I install the npm package trying to instantiate the Example class the `ExternalTypes.Options` types are not known.

**My question:**

How do I use external typescript types in a NPM package so, that users of that npm package get the types as well? Do I need to install types which are supposed to be public as dependency instead of as devDepedency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to install types which are supposed to be public as dependency instead of as devDepedency?

This is what I do.

When npm installs a package, it also installs `dependencies` but not `devDependencies`. Your package user needs `ExternalTypes.Options`, so it's required to declare it as a dependency.